# How to create a Php multi insertion?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I am trying to prepare an insertion inside the database with php, but i can't find any suggestions on how to use the syntax, this is what I've got so far, could someone help me with this please?

```
   $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

   $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `table`(name, surname) VALUES (?,?) , (?,?)");

   $query->bind_param("ss", ($nameOne, $last_id), ($nametWO, $last_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

the binding should be

```
$query->bind_param("ssss", $nameOne, $last_id, $nametWO, $last_id);
```